# Auxiliary parameter in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm trying to manage invitations to an event with a "participation" model. I'd like that, when I invite a user, i could insert his name in the form, instead of user_id.

user.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :id, :name
       has_many :participations
  end
```

participation.rb

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :event_id, :user_id
    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

end
```

views/participations/new.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(@participation) do |f| %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>
          <%= f.label :user_id, 'User Id' %>
          <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
          <%= f.submit 'Invite' %>
  <% end %>
```

How can i do?

Comment: What about a `drop-down box` showing the list of users names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by this:

```
<%= form_for(@participation) do |f| %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>
          <%= f.label :user_id, 'User Id' %>
          <%=f.collection_select :user_id,User.all,:id,:name,:label => "User" ,:include_blank => false%>
          <%= f.submit 'Invite' %>
  <% end %>
```

You may turn `include_blank` to `true` or `false` as you wish to always have a user or not.
Feel free to ask for more if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it works!! But I'd like that who invite can write user name by himself, and then, the participations_controller could obtain user_id from the name. Is it possible? I mean, something like sending an auxiliary parameter through the form. Alternatively, How can i implement autocomplete option for collection_select field?

Comment: yes you can add but if you add simple text field and can search for person with name in controller. but if not found what will happen ?

Comment: I think to visualize an error message. How the controller can access to the parameter?   if i write in the view..      <input type="text" name = "name" >. Alternatively, How can i implement autocomplete option for collection_select field?